# how to redraw field?

Tags: blackberry

I'm trying to implement my own progress bar. I have a constructor, that inits my progress bar and method to draw it:

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) 
    {
        g = graphics; //remember graphics to redraw it later
        ResizeImage r = new ResizeImage();
        Picture = r.sizeImage(Picture, Width, Height);
        graphics.drawBitmap(1, 1, Width, Height, Picture.getBitmap(), 0, 0); //dwaring background

        Cursor = r.sizeImage(Cursor, Height, Height);
        graphics.drawBitmap(1+(Width-Height*2)*Progress/(Maximum - Minimum), 1, Height, Height, Cursor.getBitmap(), 0, 0); //drawing cursor
    }
```

so, that class draws my progress bar with any cursor location. since that, all works perfect.
I have a method that should redraw my progress bar , to set cursor to another location:

```
public void SetProgress (int p) {   
        Progress = p;
        if (Progress<Minimum) Progress = Minimum;
        if (Progress>Maximum) Progress = Maximum;
        this.paint(g);
    }
```

but it draw nothing. Am i missing something? **How to redraw field?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just call invalidate and that should repaint the screen.

so replace `this.paint(g)` with `invalidate();`